# Git installation: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz

Tags: installation, git, libraries

I'm trying to install git from source as a non-root user. After typing "make" the following error occurs:

```
Link git-daemon
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I already installed libz from source and set the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to "$HOME/lib". This dir contains libz.a, libz.so, libz.so.1 and libz.so.1.2.5.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm unable to find the `-lz` option on either a GNU based Linux box or a BSD based OS X system.  It sounds like there may be a bug in the package you're trying to install.  What platform are you attempting to install git-daemon on?

Comment: @d34dh0r53: The option is `-l`, with an argument "`z`"; meaning "link against `libz`", it exists on all linkers in some form or other.

Answer (score 2):

`$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for the dynamic *loader* `ld-linux.so`, and is only used when executing already compiled and linked binaries.

When linking, you need to specify the library path using `-L`, as in `-L$HOME/lib`. With projects using autoconf (`./configure`), you can specify the flag in `$LDFLAGS`:

```
export dir="$HOME"
export CFLAGS="-I$dir/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L$dir/lib"
```

Answer (score 2):

To successfully build git from source without link errors I had to set the `$LIBRARY_PATH` variable, in addition to `$CFLAGS` and `$LDFLAGS`:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/lib"
```

Comment: Thank you. I had the exact same issue that I coud solve with this answer.